# Log Apache POST data

Tags: apache

I've been running across a few articles today pertaining to this specific topic, but I'm constantly running into an error -- not sure if it's because the articles are old and default configs have changed since then or what.

I basically want to log POST data from my web server. I've tried following articles such as: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-mod_dumpio-log-post-data/, but there's no such thing as "DumpIOInput On" inside of my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf file. Therefore, the rest of those instructions are useless for me at this point.

I'm not exactly too familiar with modules in Apache, so "use this module" might not help much although I'll research it. Just a heads up.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Is there not a way to mark a comment as answer? :\

Comment: The idea of that article is that you _enable that module_, and it does not matter there is no such config in your current setup: add it to your configuration (note: putting them in an ifModule makes send).

Comment: Just tried adding:

DumpIOInput On
DumpIOLogLevel debug (the DumpIO part doesn't become colored, so not sure if this works or not)
DumpIOOutput On

and restarted Apache server. The log file doesn't appear to be any different than it was before I added those lines.

Comment: The _error log file_ doesn't appear different?

Comment: I mean there's stuff being added of course after restarting Apache such as invalid URL, etc., but when I enter data into the form on the website and submit the POST request, there's nothing in the logs that show my POST data.

Comment: Ah, found it: your normal `LogLevel` needs to _match_ `DumpIOLogLevel` (it's not the level of dumpio-logging, it's the `LogLevel` at which `dumpio` kicks in). So, both to `debug` works (which I would recommend, as it is for debugging), but _both_ to for instance `notice` works as well.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks for your help man. I'm still having a bit trouble though. So I have "LogLevel debug", "DumpIOInput On", "DumpIOOutput On", and "DumpIOLogLevel debug" set, but when I restart the web server and post on the form again, I still don't see anything in there :\

Comment: Here's a screenshot of those options set too: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2526790/10-23-2013%204-02-14%20PM.png

Not sure if the uncolored DebugIOLogLevel option means it's not a valid one or not.

Comment: Ah, sweet. Just ran across a post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445363/why-cant-i-get-apache2-mod-dumpio-working-under-lucid-lynx-ubuntu) pertaining to changing the LogLevel under sites-enabled/000-default. After changing this, I got it to work. However, not sure if this is the safest way to do it or not. I appreciate your help man!