# Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) - mod_dumpio not logging post data

Tags: apache, post, module

I can't seem to get the Apache module **mod_dumpio** to log anything.

I have tried the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445363/why-cant-i-get-apache2-mod-dumpio-working-under-lucid-lynx-ubuntu)

To be sure I have tried the following

1. Disabled all of my vhosts except the one for the site I am working on
2. Ran **a2enmod dump_io**, and **restarted Apache**, can see it in **/etc/apache/mods-enabled/dump_io.load**
3. Check that /etc/apache/apache.conf **LogLevel** is **dumpio:trace7** too
4. I open the log tail **-f n 20 /var/log/apache2/packager-access.log**
5. Run the following command to send some post data **--data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://packager.local/api/package/create**
6. Can only see lines like **127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2014:10:07:04 +0000] "POST /api/package/create HTTP/1.1" 500 294 "-" "curl/7.35.0"**

The vhost conf is as below

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/packager/web
        ServerName lms-packager.local

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/packager-error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/packager-access.log combined

        DumpIOInput On
        DumpIOOutput On
        LogLevel dumpio:trace7
    </VirtualHost>
```

Is there anything else that I could try

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading [this post](http://objectmix.com/apache/673650-cant-get-mod_dumpio-work.html#post2352249), I tried to move the configuration to the server level.

As the post suggests the key point from the Apache manual is

> **server config** This means that the directive may be used in the server
>   configuration files (e.g., httpd.conf), but not within any
>    or  containers. It is not allowed in
>   .htaccess files at all.

The following is also important so only check your ErrorLog file (e.g. /var/log/apache2/error.log) rather than any vhost file which makes sense if this is a server config

> to be logged (dumped) to the error.log file

Comment: I still have problem with this module, my directives are in server main apache config file. and are not in any vhost.
how did you manage to handle this problem?