# how to config apache in xampp for logging post request

Tags: apache, logging, xampp, http-post, config

I run xampp and host DVWA on it. but didn't log all of http request and post request.
how to change apache config file (httpd) to log full request?
thanks.
my apache config file is:
https://www.filemail.com/d/vvkrdbixuqiaujz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I fix it:
according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445363/why-cant-i-get-apache2-mod-dumpio-working-under-lucid-lynx-ubuntu)
first uncomment `LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so` and second added this lines to httpd.conf in xampp:

```
<IfModule dumpio_module>
  DumpIOInput On
  DumpIOOutput On
  LogLevel warn dumpio:trace7
</IfModule>
```

and restart apache.
now if search in error.log find text in post body.

Answer (score 0):

When you say full request I guess you mean body of requests here is the simplified [guide](https://www.simplified.guide/apache/log-post)

Comment: thanks yes body of request. but i saw this post before and the file uploaded in my link is different from file from this link that you send

Comment: Read the comment in your file from line 329. If you still cant make it work let me know.

Comment: ok thanks too and i read it and change it to this ( LoadModule dumpio): 
https://www.filemail.com/d/nwtvngbkneiqilh
but not work and the post log don't show.